# Offline Anaconda Installation package

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, offline

This is relatively simple question but after surfing on internet for about an hour, I have to ask. I am looking for Anaconda offline installation but couldn't find any link to the installer. According to [this](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-repository/admin-guide/install/airgap-archive/) link, installer must be around 30GB for windows 64 bit. But in [archvies](https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/) I am not able to see this file.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the instructions to install the complete Anaconda enterprise repository, among other things. This is probably not what you are looking for and is also not available for free.

What you want is what can be found in the normal installation instructions:

Installing Anaconda on a non-networked machine (air gap)

> 1. Obtain a local copy of the appropriate Anaconda installer for the non-networked machine. You can copy the Anaconda installer to the target machine using many different methods, including a portable hard drive, USB drive, or CD.
> 2. After copying the installer to the non-networked machine, follow the detailed installation instructions for your operating system.

So simply download the usual anaconda installer for your machine on an online machine, transfer it to your offline computer and install